# Use the setText of RecyclerView for a url connect

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I feel like this should be obvious but I can't figure it out, I have a `RecyclerView` that gets the text set from a company array when the user clicks on one of the cards I want to send the company number text value in a URL connect. any help is appreciated

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "CompanyTitle";
public static final String KEY_TYPE = "CompanyType";
public static final String KEY_NUMBER = "CompanyNumber";
private ArrayList<Officer> officerList;
private TextView textView;

static final String API_URL = "https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/";
private List<Company> companies;
private Context context;
public MyAdapter(List<Company> companies, Context context) {
    this.companies = companies;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycle, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    Company company = companies.get(i);
    viewHolder.textViewHead.setText(company.getCompanyTitle());
    viewHolder.textviewDesc.setText(company.getCompanyType());
    viewHolder.textViewNumber.setText(company.getCompanyNumber());
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ///send these to nodes them attach the officers, get both in nodes and send to myview
            Company company1 = companies.get(i);
            Intent skipintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Nodes.class);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, company1.getCompanyTitle());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
            //  view.getContext().startActivity(skipintent);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, company1.getCompanyTitle());
            bundle.putString(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            bundle.putString(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
            skipintent.putExtras(bundle);
            new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return companies.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewHead;
    private TextView textviewDesc;
    private TextView textViewNumber;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewHead = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewhead);
        textviewDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewDesc);
        textViewNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewNumber);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    }

}

}
    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        private Exception exception;
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            ////here dont know how to access from before
            String companynumber = textViewNumber
            try {
                //cant firgure it out
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + textViewNumber +"/officers");
```

I have tried searching by id but I can't get it to work, my XML is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace your AsyncTask with input parameters:

```
 class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
```

2. Pass the number to async task when starting it:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(company1.getCompanyNumber());
```

3. Use data in the `doInBackground` method of the task:

```
public String doInBackground(String... numbers) {
  String companyNumber = numbers[0];
  // companyNumber now contains company1.getCompanyNumber()
}
```